# netbeans cunit tests cases never end

Tags: c, testing, netbeans, cunit

Trying to test my C project on NetBeans, the tests never end while the output is:

```
   Test: testFileOne ...passed   Test: testFileTwo ...passed

 Run Summary:    Type  Total    Ran Passed Failed Inactive
               suites      1      1    n/a      0        0
                tests      2      2      2      0        0
              asserts      8      8      8      0      n/a

 Elapsed time =    0.000 seconds
```

Even if it seems complete, the progress bar is still shining at the value 0.0%.

Test cases are all like:

```
void testMethod() {
     CU_ASSERT(1 == 1);
     //other lines of code..
     CU_ASSERT(0 == 0);
 }
```

with more than one CU_ASSERT for each function.
Some behaviour with auto-generated test code by NetBeans.

The command

```
make test
```

from command line works like a charme and ends with no problem.

Anybody has encountered this issue before? any way to get it solved without strambling my laptop? Thank you in advance for every comment.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Do you start any threads in your test cases that don't end when the test itself ends regularly?

Comment: Add printf's to track execution and see that the unit test really exits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a debugger (e.g gdb) to trace what happens.

This will require debugging flags to be added to your cunit code. Assuming you're using gcc, this will be the -g flag.

After compiling with debugging flags you can simply start the test binary with with the debugger, the way you'd debug a normal program.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Netbeans requires a certain directive a to stop the Test Suite and this is exactly `printf("%%SUITE_FINISHED%% time=0\n");`. Here is how your test should look like (either you are using plain vanilla C or some library like CUnit):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void test1() {
    // do your stuff
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("%%SUITE_STARTING%% mysimpletest\n");
    printf("%%SUITE_STARTED%%\n");

    printf("%%TEST_STARTED%% test1 (mysimpletest)\n");
    test1();
    printf("%%TEST_FINISHED%% time=0 test1 (mysimpletest) \n");

    printf("%%SUITE_FINISHED%% time=0\n");

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```